# Registering Delphi app to handle file type on iOS

Tags: ios, delphi, file-association

I found this article on how to associate an xCode iOS app with a file type / extension:

[Email Tutorial for iOS: How To Import and Export App Data Via Email in your iOS App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1980/email-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app)

Which says:

> other app wants to send your app a file, it does so
>   via one of two methods: via application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions,
>   passing the URL in the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey, or via
>   application:handleOpenURL.

Will Delphi be able to do the above as well? It has been a long time since I last used Delphi for mobile, but I am contemplating buying it again. I just want to make sure there are no showstoppers to stop me from doing things like this.

I have found this which might indicate that it is possible with recent versions of Delphi although not 100% sure:

- http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=115594

And someone else "hacking" units in an earlier version (close to the same problem)

- http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.ios/can-a-firemonkey-app-s-appdelegate-res/1989168

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely do it with Delphi. The more interesting question is if FMX supports it so it is ready to use without patching FMX.

FMX/XE8 implements `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`. When this is called, FMX will send a `TApplicationEvent.OpenURL` application event with `TiOSOpenApplicationContext` as context using the TMessageManager. You can subscribe to that message.

I don't see any file url handling in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. You'd have to patch FMX.Platform.iOS for that.

Comment: i think both are necessary. Thanks for the update. I am awarding bounty, but further answers, comments etc. are welcome.